# parse_str, parse_url

Tags: php, string, parsing, youtube-api, parse-url

I've been using parse_url and parse_str in order to get the ?v= from youtube.com links, unfortunatly it seems youtube passes video ID's that begin with both underscores and hyphens.

As a result,

```
$url = parse_url($url);
$vid = parse_str($url['query'], $output);
$video_id = $output['v'];
```

Gives me malformed ID's where -'s are changed to _ - Is there anyway to tell parse_url, parse_str to not exhibit this behaviour? or some other work around?

Ideally I want to avoid regex..

Comment: It seems fine to me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2B8ByK

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KTo1Nxyp1A&feature=plcp
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7y2pIZqPrU&feature=plcp
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqT-1krLL90&feature=plcp
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DDIFWBufrY&feature=plcp
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qolAwvSjkY&feature=plcp                      for example all give $video_id's that aren't a genuine reflection of    $v= due to parse_url and parse_str

Comment: I have taken a closer look at this and I can actually get it work with all of those URLs just fine, I am unsure why yours aint working.

Comment: This appears to be a PHP bug. It works fine on 5.3.10 but not 5.3.13. (I'm having the same issue.)